# MVC5 : The resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, post

I am fetching data from a table and displaying it. Every row in the webpage will have a edit hyperlink. That pops up a edit window for respective row. The contents of the pop up are replaced by the @Html.Partial() function. now the form gets submitted from the Partial view. The Interesting fact is first time I edit any row it works fine. However the second time I am getting the following error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Edit

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2623.0

```
           [HttpPost]
          [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
          public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "SerialNumber,ProjectName,Nature,Phase,StartDate,EndDate,ProjectLead,LeadAlias,Onsite,OffShore,ProjectDetail,EditedBy,CreatedBy")] ProjectModel projectModel)
          {


            projectModel.EditTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(projectModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(projectModel);

           }
```

The form gets submitted using the following button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" formaction="Edit"  formmethod="post" />
```

Please let me know if anything else do you need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give full relative url ? `formaction="/Projects/Edit"`. You may consider using the `Url.Action` helper to generate the correct url.

Comment: Changing the formaction worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@shyju 's answer really helped I changed the formaction and it worked